# Regarding conditional operator '?' , can some one explain this to me, in simple if else format?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

Regarding conditional operator '?' , can some one explain this to me, in simple if else format?
AutoFFSuccess, ActSuccess, FUPSuccess are bool values.

```
char StatusCode = (AutoFFSuccess) ?
                     (ActSuccess) ? 
                     'P' : 'W' : (FUPSuccess) ?
                     (ActSuccess) ?
                     'F' : 'G' : 'E';
```

Comment: Which part is unclear? [MSDN for ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: Note that although this is good as an logic-exercise it's terrible if you use this kind of code in a 'real' application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normally format that like this:

```
char statusCode = AutoFFSuccess ? ActSuccess ? 'P' : 'W' 
                                : FUPSuccess ? ActSuccess ? 'F' : 'G'
                                             : 'E'
```

Or:

```
char statusCode;

if (AutoFFSuccess)
{
    if (ActSuccess)
    {
        statusCode = 'P';
    }
    else
    {
        statusCode = 'W';
    }
}
else
{
    if (FUPSuccess)
    {
        if (ActSuccess)
        {
            statusCode = 'F';
        }
        else
        {
            statusCode = 'G';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        statusCode = 'E';
    }
}
```

It's really not very nice though.

Rather than express it with conditionals nested in that way, I'd separate each option out, using "stacked" single conditional operators. Note that some people don't like this, but I find it rather simple, once you're used to it:

```
char statusCode = 
       AutoFFSuccess && ActSuccess ? 'P'
     : AutoFFSuccess ? 'W'
     : FUPSuccess && ActSuccess ? 'F'
     : FUPSuccess ? 'G'
     : 'E';
```

Or to be more explicit:

```
char statusCode = 
       AutoFFSuccess && ActSuccess ? 'P'
     : AutoFFSuccess && !ActSuccess? 'W'
     : !AutoFFSuccess && FUPSuccess && ActSuccess ? 'F'
     : !AutoFFSuccess && FUPSuccess && !ActSuccess ? 'G'
     : 'E';
```

(I'm assuming the conditions won't change between evaluations, mind you...)

Comment: Missed a `W` somewhere ;-) ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
char StatusCode;
if (AutoFFSuccess)
{
    if (ActSuccess)
        StatusCode = 'P';
    else
        StatusCode = 'W';
}
else if (FUPSuccess)
{
    if (ActSuccess)
        StatusCode = 'F';
    else
        StatusCode = 'G';
}
else
    StatusCode = 'E';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(AutoFFSuccess){
if(ActSuccess)
    statuscode='P';
else
    statuscode='W';
}

else if(FUPSuccess){
if(ActSuccess)
    statuscode='F';
else
    statuscode='G';

}
else  statuscode = 'E';
```

Comment: This answer is just fine.  The OP asked to convert code using `?:` to the equivalent if-else chain, and that's what this answer does.  (See the other similar answers posted around the same time.)

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode:

```
if AutoFFSuccess is true:
    if ActSuccess is true:
        StatusCode is 'P'
    else:
        StatusCode is 'W'
else:
    if FUPSuccess is true:
        if ActSuccess is true:
            StatusCode is 'F'
        else:
            StatusCode is 'G'
    else:
        StatusCode is 'E'
```